# Error disabling COM Add-IN in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, ms-office, office-addins

Within my own PowerPoint Add-In, I have been disabling a seperate add-in using the code below for quite some time:

```
For Each COMAddIn As COMAddIn In PowerPointApp.COMAddIns
    If COMAddIn.ProgId = "addinname" And COMAddIn.Connect = True Then
        Try
            COMAddIn.Connect = False
        Catch ex As Exception
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Disable Failed: " + ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If
Next COMAddIn
```

However on my new computer I get the output:

> Disable Failed: This add-in is installed for all users on this
>   computer and can only be connected or disconnected by an
>   administrator.

I initially thought that I would have to run PowerPoint as administrator for my code to work; however this isn't an good option.

Furthermore, I can manually disable the add-in without running PowerPoint as administrator.

Do PowerPoint Add-Ins have a separate Privilege level to the instance of PowerPoint? Can you not disable add-ins for all users through code?

Not sure how to solve this problem.